# Como probar un metodo privado que es llamado dentro de un metodo publico en Java con Mockito y JUnit?

Tags: java, spring, junit, pruebas-unitarias, mockito

Soy nuevo dentro del tema de pruebas unitarias en Java y actualmente tengo que realizarlas en la aplicación que recién termine de desarrollar, ya logre completar algunas, sin embargo, llegue a un método que es publico dentro del cual se invoca a otro método pero que es privado, vi algunos ejemplos de como testear un metodo privado pero no entiendo muy bien.

El metodo esta estructurado asi:

```
//METODO PUBLICO
public void generarArchivoProd(int anio, int mes, int dia, String paginacion){
 
if("1".equals(paginacion){

 haz esto.....

}
else{ 

haz esto otro 

}
 //INVOCACION DEL METODO PRIVADO
 this.imprimeDocumento(Long.value("0"),"",mes,anio,dia, paginacion);

}


//METODO PRIVADO
private void imprimeDocumento(Long, int, int, int, String){
 ...............
}
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo alcanzar el método privado al testear el método publico? Como deberia ser la estructura correcta de la prueba para lograr esto?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general, no se realiza pruebas unitarias de métodos privados directamente. Dado que son privados, considérelos un detalle de implementación. Nadie va a llamar a uno de ellos y esperar que funcione de una manera particular.

En el caso que expones al probar tu metodo `generarArchivoProd(int anio, int mes, int dia, String paginacion)` debería quedar cubierta la cobertura de código de tu metodo privado si eso es lo que buscas. Si quieres saber si se ejecuto, podrías usar [Mockito#verify](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html)